# Is $x\mapsto x^2$ (map) from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (real numbers), the same as $f(x)=x^2$ and not injective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For example in: $f(x)=x^2$  from the set of real numbers real numbers to real numbers is not an injective function because of this kind of thing:

$f(2) = 4$ and
$f(-2) = 4$
This is against the definition $f(x) = f(y), x = y$, because $f(2) = f(-2)$ but $2 ≠ -2$

In other words there are two values of A that point to one B.

But I just don't understand if the notation is the same? Can I use the same example to prove this?

Comment: Welcome to the MSE! Your post would look nicer if you use mathJax. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a mathJax tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a difference in notation.

What is $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) = x^2$? It is a function that **maps** elements $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to elements $x^2\in\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, $f(x)=x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is the map:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: amazing thank you so much :)!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, writing $x\mapsto x^2$ signifies the same function as writing $f(x)=x^2$, but *without giving it a name*. Some times you don't need to refer back to that function later, and need all the letters for other things, so having nameless (anonymous) functions can be useful.

Comment: amazing thank you so much :)!!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I would say that the two notations are equivalent.

You can either write $f(x)=x^2$ or $x\mapsto x^2$ to express the same idea: $x$ is mapped to its square.

The difference between the two is that the first gives an explicit name to the function, namely $f$, while the second does not.

Specifying the domain is something else. Both can be used on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ or restricted to some subdomain.

Comment: amazing thank you so much :)!!